# Detox android : Tap action has effect but the test timeouts

Tags: detox

Tap action has an effect on the emulator by showing next screen. But the test timeouts.
This issue is similar to github issue https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1699

Comment: Same issue here, apparently it is an issue about synchronisation and maybe react-navigation, adb logcat says Detox   : UIManagerModule is busy.

Test are all good with iOS, but with Android calling .tap(); function hangs all the tests.

If someone has a workaround please tell us :D

Thanks.

Comment: @YanvegHD i have answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link : https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2652

The issue was with animation which blocks from going idle. Please take a look at the above issue.